# Make a menu item unselectable

Tags: themes, menus

I'd like to make the main menu selection for some menu items not selectable. For example, I'm doing a resume and I have a "Work History" page with "Job 1", "Job 2", etc. as children. I'd like to be able to select the children but not the "Work History". Is there a clean (or for that matter dirty) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Admin - Appearance -Menues

leave the URL field for "Work History" empty, but fill the UL fields for the "Job 1", "Job 2", etc.

Comment: Thanks, but when I go to the "Work History" Edit Page, I don't see a URL field. I do see a permalink field, but that didn't let me get rid of it.

I should also note that this is the main menu that you get by adding pages. If I want this behavior, should I do it a different way?

Comment: I also tried creating a custom menu and using that, but it wouldn't let me add an item with a blank URL. I also didn't see how to add the Job 1, etc. as children with the custom menu.

Comment: OK, figured it out. Create a Custom Menu. Add a Custom Link (must have a URL or it won't let you add to the menu). You can then drag/drop Job pages onto this new link. Edit the link to remove the URL (it's OK at this point). Save menu and everything should work.